# Cumulative sum sorted descending within a group. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've faced a problem while applying sort_values() and cumsum() within a group.

I have a dataaset:

[image]

Basically, I need to sort values within a group, get cumulative sales and select those lines that compose 90% of sales.

to get first

[image]

and then, just select 90% of sales within each region

[image]

I have tried the following but the last line doesn't work. I returns an error: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

I've tried apply also..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id_1', 
'id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6','id_7','id_8', 'id_1', 
'id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6','id_7','id_8'],
               'region':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,],
               'sales':[54,34,23,56,78,98,76,34,27,89,76,54,34,45,56,54]})
df['%']=df['sales']/df.groupby(df['region'])['sales'].transform('sum')
df['cumul'] = df.groupby(df['region'])['sales'].sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum()
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely sort the dataframe first, then do `groupby()`:

```
df.sort_values(['region','sales'], ascending=[True,False],inplace=True)

df['%']=df['sales']/df.groupby(df['region'])['sales'].transform('sum')

df['cummul'] = df.groupby('region')['%'].cumsum()

# filter
df[df['cummul'].le(0.9)]
```

Output:

```
      id  region  sales         %    cummul
5   id_6       1     98  0.216336  0.216336
4   id_5       1     78  0.172185  0.388521
6   id_7       1     76  0.167770  0.556291
3   id_4       1     56  0.123620  0.679912
0   id_1       1     54  0.119205  0.799117
1   id_2       1     34  0.075055  0.874172
9   id_2       2     89  0.204598  0.204598
10  id_3       2     76  0.174713  0.379310
14  id_7       2     56  0.128736  0.508046
11  id_4       2     54  0.124138  0.632184
15  id_8       2     54  0.124138  0.756322
13  id_6       2     45  0.103448  0.859770
```

Comment: Nice one BTW do you have the problem stackover auto log you off just happened to me few mins ago

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang I didn’t think that sorting can be done by two variables. It turned out that all is easier than i seemed first:)

Comment: @WeNYoBen no, it didn't happen to me.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, is it possible to do sorting by multiple columns? I'm trying to implement something with the third variable but it doesn't work..

Comment: Yes, you can do `sort_values([col1,col2,col3,col4...])` and pass  `ascending = [True, False,...]` with the same length as the list of columns.

Comment: First, I was trying to sort the third variable by splitting string, but it didn't work. I just created additional variable and this simplified version works! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First we use your logic to create the `%` column, but we `multiply` by `100` and `round` to whole numbers.

Then we sort by `region` and `%`, no need for `groupby`.

After we sort, we create the `cumul` column.

And finally we select those within the `90%` range with `query`:

```
df['%'] = df['sales'].div(df.groupby('region')['sales'].transform('sum')).mul(100).round()
df = df.sort_values(['region', '%'], ascending=[True, False])
df['cumul'] = df.groupby('region')['%'].cumsum()

df.query('cumul.le(90)')
```

**output**

```
      id  region  sales     %  cumul
5   id_6       1     98  22.0   22.0
4   id_5       1     78  17.0   39.0
6   id_7       1     76  17.0   56.0
0   id_1       1     54  12.0   68.0
3   id_4       1     56  12.0   80.0
1   id_2       1     34   8.0   88.0
9   id_2       2     89  20.0   20.0
10  id_3       2     76  17.0   37.0
14  id_7       2     56  13.0   50.0
11  id_4       2     54  12.0   62.0
15  id_8       2     54  12.0   74.0
13  id_6       2     45  10.0   84.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the sales data without the percentage, this can easily be done with method chaining:

```
(
  df
  .sort_values(by='sales', ascending=False)
  .groupby('region')
  .apply(lambda x[x.sales > x.sales.quantile(.1)])
  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)
```

Output

```
      id  region  sales
5   id_6       1     98
4   id_5       1     78
6   id_7       1     76
3   id_4       1     56
0   id_1       1     54
1   id_2       1     34
7   id_8       1     34
9   id_2       2     89
10  id_3       2     76
14  id_7       2     56
11  id_4       2     54
15  id_8       2     54
13  id_6       2     45
12  id_5       2     34
```

This works because getting all values greater than 10% is essentially the same as getting the top 90%.

Comment: Thank you @shwanky!  I didnt try to sort first and then apply group by, because i thought that the whole column will be sorted. In fact, it works as intended. Thanks

Comment: @vero You might also want to consider the [interpolation method of quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.htm), since the quantile value might possibly be in between two of your data points.